# OWL cardinality restriction issue

Tags: owl, semantic-web, ontology, protege, pellet

As picture below depicted, `a` is a defined class `has_relation min 2 b`.
Also `c` is a named class `(has_relation min 1 b1) and (has_relation min 1 b2)`

[image]
[image]

pellet reasoner does not classify `c` as a subclass of `a`.what is wrong in the definition of `c`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#has_relation -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#has_relation"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#a -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#a">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#has_relation"/>
                <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">2</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
                <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b1 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b1">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b2 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b2">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b3 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b3">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#c -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#c">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#has_relation"/>
                <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
                <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b1"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#has_relation"/>
                <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
                <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2019/11/untitled-ontology-123#b2"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

Answer (score 2):

`b` subclasses `(b1,b2)` Must be disjoint with each other.otherwise reasoner cant decide `b1` and `b2` are the same or distinct members.

I think this refer to the open world assumption discussion.

Comment: I'd say this doesn't refer to OWA: these classes can simply overlap each other. Let suppose a man have to bring into existence a tree and a house. But what if he lives under the tree he planted?

Comment: OWA is not involved because it's enough to find one example for a valid instance of c that is not an instance of a. Assume there's a filler individual for has_relation which is instance of b1 and b2, as Stanislav mentions, then all individuals for which it is a filler are instances of c but not of a because there's only one assertion. Iow in your definition of c you can move the and to the filler class.